# How to update local git tracking of remote repo when it delete a branch

Tags: git

Such as, I have deleted the patch-1 branch in [github.com](https://github.com/Honghe/Biopython-cn), and run `git fetch origin` to update local repo to track the remote, but the command `git branch -a` still show I local repo tracking `remotes/origin/patch-1`.

```
$ git branch -a
* master
  origin
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/patch-1
```

So, how to update my local repo?
Thx!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're after [`git fetch --prune` / `git fetch -p`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-fetch.html),

> `-p`
>   `--prune`
>
> After fetching, remove any remote-tracking branches which no longer exist on the remote.